# C# - Utilize Quest active directory cmdlets for Powershell by calling PS script

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, quest

**C# code** ([Source](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C)):

```
private string RunScript(string scriptText)
{
    // create Powershell runspace

    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

    // open it

    runspace.Open();

    // create a pipeline and feed it the script text

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

    // add an extra command to transform the script
    // output objects into nicely formatted strings

    // remove this line to get the actual objects
    // that the script returns. For example, the script

    // "Get-Process" returns a collection
    // of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.

    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

    // execute the script

    Collection<psobject /> results = pipeline.Invoke();

    // close the runspace

    runspace.Close();

    // convert the script result into a single string

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

**Powershell code**

```
#Dummy code for example purpose

ASNP Quest*
#Example of cmdlet I want to use
$Users = Get-QADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Enabled
return $Users.count
```

As you can see, my goal is to call the script utilizing `RunScript` above in a `Button_Click event` in my WPF app. I've been able to correctly call the script but the call to Quest cmdlets clearly doesn't go trough as wanted since I would receive 0 in the above example.

**TL;DR**

Script is running correctly but calls to Quest cmdlets don't work since it return nothing (or 0 in the above example). Is there something I'm missing ?

**EDIT**

Important to note that the exact same script ran in Powershell returns the correct values. Calling it from C# don't.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Within c# you mean ?

Comment: Is there a reason your using c# at all? Powershell has support for WPF front-ends

Comment: @MikeGaruccio Not very well.  It's significantly more effort if you're doing anything slightly advanced.

Comment: I'm not sure the `Out-String` command is doing what you hope for.  You seem to be confusing executing a full script and a separate command.  Can you get _anything_ to return?  For example, a simple string or output from, say, `Get-Process`?  This will rule out the Quest cmdlets.

Comment: @boxdog good call. Just tried, and `Get-Proscess` is returned exactly as I would expect. As i said, I get return values in the good form, but calling Quest cmdlets don't return correct values. BTW, calling directly from PS returns correct values. Added edit accordingly.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm trying to import it but I"m not sure i"m doing it correctly.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Already tried, without success _The term 'Import-Module -Name QuestAD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program._

Comment: Are you using `Import-Module` in your script?  I'd suggest adding that command there.  Is the module named QuestAD?  I was guessing.

Comment: If it's a possibility, try using the Microsoft `ActiveDirectory` module.  I tried your C# code with that and it works fine (using `Get-ADGroupMember`).  I don't have the Quest cmdlets to test with.  Incidentally, where is `$group` defined? I just substituted a hard-coded name for my test, but it isn't clear where you are defining it.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 the correct command seems to be `Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement` but adding it to the top of my script didn't work...

Comment: Add this to the head of your script: `#Requires -PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 _the following snap-ins that are specified by the "#requires" statements of the script are missing: Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement.'_ So the problem comes from there... I'll look into it. Thanks !

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 @boxdog @Mike Garuccio Found the problem... Was a real pain to debug. It had nothing to do with importing... I was calling a `Get-Content` on a file which wasn't correctly resolved, i was therefore comparing against null values. I'm truly thankful for your time and sorry my bug was directly related to the question. Should I remove the post ?

Comment: @scharette Usually typos / simple mistakes are closed so I'd say yes

Comment: I'ts not really a typo but if others agree I will.